# Filter nested list of matrix by row name

Tags: r, list, matrix, filter, subset

I have a list of matrix, which was webscraped.  I am looking to filter each matrix by row and column name. I can filter matrix by rownames and lists but not matrix in a list!

**Some data**

```
set.seed(1)

a_matrix  <-  matrix(sample(0:100, 16), ncol=4)
b_matrix <- matrix(sample(0:100, 16), ncol=4)
dimnames(a_matrix) <- list(rownames(a_matrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "row"),
                          colnames(a_matrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "col"))

dimnames(b_matrix) <- list(rownames(b_matrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "row"),
                           colnames(b_matrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "col"))
a_matrix
      col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   26   19   58   61
row2   37   86    5   33
row3   56   97   18   66
row4   89   62   15   42

b_matrix
      col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   13   21   86   12
row2    1   77   93   39
row3   44   64   74   47
row4   17   69   80   22

my_list <- list(a_matrix,b_matrix)


Filtering the whole list by:
 
names <- c("col1", "col2", "row2", "row3")
```

**Ideal Result**

```
a_matrix
      col1 col2  
row2   37   86   
row3   56   97   


b_matrix
      col1 col2 
row2    1   77   
row3   44   64
```

Whilst still remaining in a list.

Comment: Try `lapply(my_list, \(x) x[names[3:4], names[1:2]])`

Comment: Your code doesn't work, what is `rmatrix`? And always use `set.seed()` when random processes are involved, to make the results reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `list` with `lapply`, subset the matrix with row/column names from the `names` vector where the elements 3 to 4 are the row names attribute, and 1 to 2 are the column names

```
lapply(my_list, \(x) x[names[3:4], names[1:2]])
```

-output

```
[[1]]
     col1 col2
row2   37   86
row3   56   97

[[2]]
     col1 col2
row2    1   77
row3   44   64
```

#### data

```
my_list <- list(structure(c(26L, 37L, 56L, 89L, 19L, 86L, 97L, 62L, 58L, 
5L, 18L, 15L, 61L, 33L, 66L, 42L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"), c("col1", "col2", "col3", 
    "col4"))), structure(c(13L, 1L, 44L, 17L, 21L, 77L, 64L, 
69L, 86L, 93L, 74L, 80L, 12L, 39L, 47L, 22L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L
), .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"), c("col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4"))))
```

Comment: Thank you, dont quite understand the [3:4] and the [1:2] elements of the code but it worked as i wanted!

Comment: @TDaw it is just that you created the `names` vector with the row names in positions 3rd and 4th, whereas the column names where in 1 and 2 positions in the vector

Comment: Thanks again! I understand now